# How does signed script works even there is no network connection?

Tags: powershell, signing, verisign, symantec

I have signed the powershell script with the key purchased from Verisign (symantec).

I am executing the script inside a VM where no internet connection available.

How it executes without any problem? How it will get public key if it is not connected to internet?

I am using executionpolicy as "AllSigned"

Comment: What is you Execution Policy set to on that machine?

Comment: @mjolinor It is "Allsigned"

Answer (score 1):

The signing certificate you got from Symantec is signed with a trusted key, which is likely already stored on your computer. Use `mmc.exe` and add the certificates module to the console. Browse the trusted root CA container, and you are likely to find several certificates from Symantec / Verisign or whatever. One of those is used to certify that the signing certificate you purchased is really from the issuer.